# Uphold variable life in Bash loop

Tags: bash

I am trying to find the number of files with executable permission by the owner. I am doing this but giving me error

cmd> ls -la /myScript.sh

myScript.sh is the following

```
z=0
while read line
do

    #for total lines read
    #wc -l
    #total unique user
    #top three largest directory
    #for total executables
    for i in $(echo $line | sed -n '/^-rwx/p'| wc -l)
    do
         #echo $i #process in this if-then filter out 0 and sum non-zero
         if [$i -ne 0]
         then

            echo $i
        #   $(z=z+i)

         fi
    done    


done


echo "Total executable files by owner $z";
```

Comment: Read the manual page of the `find` command, look for the `-executable` flag.

Comment: Homework problem?

Comment: aren't many here are?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `find` and `wc`.

Read their manuals. Your script can be done in one line:

```
find . -type f -perm -u=x | wc -l
```